# Finding the minimum from last K elements , after each insertion , where K is not fixed in less than O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Finding the minimum from last K elements , after each insertion , where K is not fixed:

For example Given Array 
10 2 4 1 3

```
Query K = 3
ans : 1 (minimum of 4 1 3)

Insertion : 5
10 2 4 1 3 5
Query K =2
ans = 3

Insertion 2
10 2 4 1 3 5 2
Query K =4
ans 1
```

Is there an efficient way for process such queries in less than O(n) time for each query ?

Comment: Please assume that the readers cannot read your mind, and write your question carefully in a way so that readers can actually figure out what you mean without guessing. If you want good answers, write good questions. I have no idea what a "minimum form" is supposed to be.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you know in the beginning itself the maximum number of elements that shall be inserted so that you can allocate space for them accordingly.

Then a min-segment tree shall work. Initially all elements in the segment tree contain "INT_MAX" value.

As new elements arrive, the corresponding leafs (and their ancestors) get updated. The leaf chosen for updation is as per the position of the element in the stream.

The interval queries can then be easily performed.

Both insertion and query operations shall take `O(log n)` time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to solve this problem using a array and Binary search.

First, we process the array, and maintaining a array of index with increasing value.
So, for array `10 2 4 1 3`, in the queue we have `1 3`

Every time we insert one element into array, we try to remove all elements at the end of the array, which are greater than the current element, so  when we insert 5 -> array become `1 3 5` , then insert 2 -> queue become `1 2`.

So, to query the minimum element in range K, we need to find the element in the array, which is nearest to the start of the queue, and has index in the range of the last K element, which can be easily done using binary search.

So, total time for **all** insert will be O(n) or in average O(1) per insert and for each query is O(log n).

Pseudo code

```java
int[] q;
int numberOfElement = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    while(numberOfElement > 0 && data[q[numberOfElement - 1]] >= data[i]){
          numberOfElement--;
    }
    q[numberOfElement++] = i;
}

//Insert at index i:
while(numberOfElement > 0 && data[q[numberOfElement - 1]] >= data[i]){
      numberOfElement--;
}
q[numberOfElement++] = i;

//Query for range K
int start = 0;
int end = numberOfElement - 1;
int result = 0;
while(start <= end){
     int mid = (start + end) >> 1;
     if(q[mid] >= totalElement - K){
          result = mid;
          end = mid - 1;
     } else{
          start = mid + 1;
     }
}
```

Comment: removing itself will lead to `O(n)` complexity no?

Comment: @Yerken what is removing here? remove from the input array? Nope, there is no removing allow. And about removing in the increasing array `q`, we need to notice that the total number of element in the array `q` will only be n, (as we don't re-add any element) so the total time complexity for **all** remove will be bounded by O(n).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of elements to be inserted beforehand then you can go with **`@Abhishek Bansal`** answer (segment tree). Otherwise you can use a BST (binary search tree), for example **Treap**. You use index of element in the array as a key and the value of a node is its value in the array. So insertion of an element will take `O(log(n))` and same complexity for the query (query is a max range query from last_index-k+1 to last_index, both are keys).

Here is the code for treap (it is for maxrange query) but minrange is the same idea: https://ideone.com/M9rnbg

Comment: How do you get the minimum element if key is the index ?

Comment: store min_value field in each node, for each range query u will "extract" the range and reevaluate the min_value along the cutting lines (in case of treap)

Comment: Can you add some pseudo code? Store min_value in each node? min_value of what range?

Comment: Added ideone link, it has complete code in C++ (but for maxrange)

Comment: it has lots of other features which u can ignore (lazy adding etc)

Answer (score 0):

Create and maintain a **[min-heap tree](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tcortina/15-121sp10/Unit06B.pdf)** of maximum size `k`. Before every *insertion*, you need to [**delete**](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/heap-del.html) the last `kth` inserted value from the `min-heap` tree, and after insertion min-heapify the tree.

Root node value(after *insertion*) stores the minimum value among last `k` inserted element all the time.

For each query:

Deletion costs: `O(log k)`

Insertion costs : `O(log k)`

Finding minimum costs : `O(1)`

So, overall time complexity is `O(log k)` (which is lesser than `O(n)`).